# Laravel 4 - getting crossing results of tables connected by relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

With Laravel, I created a main table `users`, with primary key, email field and password field. Than I created several other tables like `physical_details`, `personal_data`, both with a foreign key `user_id`.

Now I'm having trouble in crossing results. For example, find users with `height` = `170` (physical detail) and at the same time with `marital_status` = `married` (personal data). I tried to group the wheres, but it's getting a bit complex, and worse, results only bring the values ​​of the main table (users)

Comment: Check this out stackoverflow.com/questions/18599455/eloquent-orm-using-where-in-both-inner-join-tables

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries) to perform a [join](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins). You'll probable want something similar to the following code:

```
$result = DB::table('users')
            ->distinct() // We most likely don't want duplicate rows
            ->join('physical_details', 'users.id', '=', 'physical_details.user_id')
            ->join('personal_data', 'users.id', '=', 'personal_data.user_id')
            ->select('users.id', 'physical_details.columnX', 'personal_data.columnY')
            ->where('personal_data.marital_status', '=', 'married')
            ->where('physical_details.height', '=', 170)
            ->get();
```

Here, `$result` should be an array of objects with properties `id`, `columnX` and `columnY` (select whatever columns contain the information you're looking for).

The documentation I link to should be able to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

If relationships between tables are sets.

```
$users = User::wherehas('personnal_data',function($q) {
$q->wheremaritalStatus('Married');
})->get();

dd($users);
```

Should work ?

Regards,